# Why is NoReturn missing from __all__ in Python 3

Tags: python, annotations, typing

Looking into annotations (using Python 3.6.4), I tried `from typing import *` and noticed that `NoReturn` was not imported.

[issue28556](https://bugs.python.org/issue28556) added `NoReturn` to the typing library, but it's missing from the `__all__` list in the 3.6 and [3.7](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/typing.py) cpython sources.

Was this a deliberate omission?  Is `NoReturn` harmful in some way that warrants this omission?

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather reading the typing module code, issues and [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#the-noreturn-type), this looks like a bug. Nowhere I can see someone talking about not adding (or actually adding) `NoReturn` to the `__all__` list of either python2 or 
python3 code

Best way to be certain is probably submitting a new issue and waiting for a contributor to answer